# How would the world change if mind switching became possible?

Tags: society

Suppose science (or some other area) develops a way to switch minds relatively easily and with negligible risk to one's life; how would the world change, and how different would the possible worlds be depending on:

- Cost of transfer and machinery (restricted to rich? accessible to most but not readily? no cost once you buy a specific machine? no money required at all?)
- Legislation (consent? heavy restrictions?)
- Would consent be required for the transfer? (could body mugging be a thing?)
- Required facilities & speed (would it require days in hospital or just take a second or two?)
- Restrictions on returning to old body (perhaps one cannot use any body twice?)
- Would bodies have to be nearby, or could long-distance transfers be made?

I presume that either way one would end up with bodies being sold. But would there be rentals? Would one have, instead of today's personal trainers, people who would switch bodies with you for a couple of weeks and exercise furiously? Would possessions be linked to mind or body, and if mind, how would people prevent identity theft? How would people treat their nearest and dearest switching bodies? Would there be false accusations of switches?

Comment: @Zxyrra Copy & paste does not serve well here, methinks.

Comment: @Frostfyre Both questions happen to have the same problem, but I can edit it ----

Comment: Welcome to Worldbuilding SE! This question is likely be closed because it may be **opinion based** or **too broad**. See [this page](http://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/closed-questions) for info.

Comment: Altered Carbon series by Richard K. Morgan is an interesting exploration of this exact question.

Comment: how fantastic is the transfer? does the transferee have to learn how to see and hear with their new organs all over again like transplants recipients do?

Comment: Quite a few books on the topic. Off the top of my head: the webcomic "Sleepless", the anime "Your Name", the"Hot Chick", Hopscotch, Freaky Friday, etc. and also https://www.goodreads.com/shelf/show/body-swap (124 other titles). I've also read at least one story (sorry don't have a reference) in one of the monthly short story sci-fi magazines.

Comment: This is definitely too broad.  Its frowned upon to ask multiple questions at once.  You not only ask 5 questions, but consider 6 2-factor variables for each of them.  That's effectively 320 questions!

Comment: Most of the things you ask for are for you to decide. Better chance to get good answer is "what effect would it be if I'll set up these factors that way? Would ... happen?" or "I want ... to happen, and have these factors, how to get it?"

Answer (score 1):

One possible application: swapping minds between disabled people and people incarcerated in prisons. The argument will be, why should a decent law-abiding citizen be made to suffer reduced mobility or chronic pain while a serial killer in a high security prison be allowed the privilege of a fully healthy body.

The problem in this case may be that the demand for new bodies outmatches the supply of imprisoned criminals. This could lead to the society's judicial system gradually becoming more draconian, where even the most minor infractions will have you sent to have your mind transferred into a disabled person's body, and for you then, in that body, to be locked up in inescapable hospital/prison facilities.

Answer (score 0):

1. Depends on how expensive the materials to build the mind switching machine. Most likely it will start out exclusively for the elite one percent and over time become cheaper and more affordable for the average middle class family.
2. Consent is need for most medical procedures so I don't see why this would not be the same.
3. again depends how the machine was designed and how far into the future you want to go.
4. I don't see why unless there is some medical reason involed
5. Again depends on how your machine is made.